# Comic book story identification

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title of a comic book story about humans who land or crash land on an alien planet and have to stay alive against the plant and animal that live there. I really don't remember much about it. It was a long time ago. The art work was like Dan Dare so it might have been a British comic. It was a serial, one story out of a few in one comic, and it might have been a colony ship. from what I remember they landed in a jungle with all the plants and trees moving and trying to eat them, so not Superman. It was about 20 years ago that I saw this story. It was part one I never got to see the rest. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is really... REALLY broad and could arguably be anything that involves space-travel. Could you provide more details? Without more information, it may be impossible to get you an answer.

Comment: Maybe even just a description of the ship?  Or the plants/animals?  A character name?  Hell, you could almost stretch this question enough to cover Superman!

Answer (score 2):

It could be "[Alien Worlds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Worlds)"

[image: Alien Worlds]

[Savage Wolverine;](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savage_Wolverine)

[image: Savage Wolverine]

[Starfall](http://www.comicvine.com/starfall/4005-55660/)

[image: Starfall]

or even certain storylines in [Vampirella](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampirella).

[image: Vampirella]

Comment: Even by the poor standards of comic artists, that girl in the Savage Wolverine comic is anatomically unbelievable. Her waist is narrower than her thigh!

Comment: @DanielRoseman - In fairness I wasn't really selecting on the basis of *artistic ability*. I was more looking to fit a certain theme...

Comment: And there *definitely* seems to be a  theme to all of these, too....